# Can "research work" be treated as a plural noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, collective-nouns

I know "research work**s**" does not make sense. (I think I heard "works" is only used for art pieces.)

The problem is that I want to use "research work" to indicate *multiple* research articles. Can I simply assume it's a collective noun and make a sentence like this?

> The early research work **focus** on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No

> Early research work focused on....

"The" may or may not be correct dependent on context.

---

“Works” has a different meaning. It is used to describe construction or engineering projects.

E.g.:
There are traffic jams all over the city due to the road works in the centre.
Works on the bridge were delayed by 4 weeks due to bad weather.
The Works were signed off 6 months after the Completion Date.

So you should never use “works” to describe the work you do when you’re sitting at a desk.

Ref [Works](https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2011/02/21/don%E2%80%99t-confuse-%E2%80%9Cwork%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Cworks%E2%80%9D/)